# Check whether the entered statement is string or not?

Tags: c++

Program to find the first largest number from the entered 5 number.
When program says user to enter the first number then Check whether the entered statement is string or not if it is a string then call a user defined function in that is named as error() if it is a integer then store it and ask the user to enter second number.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are not code writing service. Try to do your homework on your own and if you stumble upon some problem, we'll be happy to help.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828937/how-to-make-cin-take-only-numbers

Comment: Technically: everything the user inputs is a string. Even if such string contains characters, that resemble integer.

Comment: [User Input of Integers - Error Handling](//stackoverflow.com/q/1283302)

Comment: Your assignment would be easier if you check that the input was an integer and call `error()` if not an integer.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17982719/509868

Answer (score 0):

You can enter integers directly via `cin` in `<iostream>`:

```
int number;
std::cin >> number;
```

If the entered string is not a number, `cin.fail()` [will be set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/):

```
if(std::cin.fail()) {
    // error handling...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for cases like "5w" and "12.34".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I've written a [small test program](https://pastebin.com/pYcGadnU) and you seem to be right. However, in the very specific case of OP, it might just be enough. If you enter "344w" and `cin` parses `344`, it is good enough to work with for a largest-number program. Concerning your second example, since OP specified *integer*, I did not look for a floating-point solution.